# How do I make BugSnag report 404 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, bugsnag

I keep getting 404 errors from people posting bad links to my site content. I realized that BugSnag isn't telling me about it, so how do I configure BugSnag to report 404 errors or throw errors in my rails app when things 404? Also, want the 404 html pages to render without Bugsnag interfering.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reporting a custom 404 [handled error](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/ruby/rails/reporting-handled-errors/) to Bugsnag:

```
begin
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
rescue => e
  Bugsnag.notify(e)
end
```

More information on Rails 404 errors found [here](https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/26/rails-render-404-not-found-from-controller-action/).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Bugsnag.  You can detect whether the status= 404, and use Bugsnag.notifyException() to send the error in.  Hope this helps.